# Bash error after Installing Conda on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, datascience-anaconda

I install Conda following the official manual on WSL Ubuntu in my desktop. However, after initiating Conda, every time launching the terminal, it shows

```
-bash: eval: line 141: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 141: `export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(base) ''
(base) root@DESKTOP-KT6HJIP:~#
```

In this conda, once activating the new environment, it shows both names of the new and base environments.

```
(base) root@DESKTOP-KT6HJIP:~# conda create -n new
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /root/miniconda3/envs/new



Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate new
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

(base) root@DESKTOP-KT6HJIP:~# conda activate new
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(new) (base) root@DESKTOP-KT6HJIP:~#
```

What's more, I cannot install packages in a new environment.

I have tried both WSL1/2 and Ubuntu-22.04/20.04, but suffered the same issue.

Any one could help me solve this problem?

Comment: Look in `.condarc` for `env_prompt` and remove parenthesis from that. retry after.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "official manual" that you are following please?

Comment: Hi, @steeldriver, here is the [link](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Comment: OK thanks - so I can't reproduce this behavior with WSL1+Ubuntu 22.04, in fact I can't see anywhere that the installer adds the instruction `export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(base) '` to any of the bash shell's regular startup files - is this something you added manually? BTW it is not recommended to run software like this as root.